# Ubuntu 18.04 loop at login, and Ctl-Alt-F1 cannot stop it!

Tags: command-line, 18.04, 17.10, lightdm

I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10 and got a login loop.
But when I started a terminal session, and did some apt update commands, it suggested I upgrade to 18.04.

I did the upgrade, but on 18.04, the same login loop appeared.

As suggested by some thread in another forum, I tried to delete and reinstall `lightdm` (I now see that lightdm may not even be used in 18.04!)

Now the system is in a login loop that does not appear to be stoppable

A <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> will bring up my login, but before I have a chance to type in my complete ID, it starts all over again.

Is there some other keyboard command I can use to stop this loop, and get control of the terminal?

Comment: I'd suggest you boot in recovery mode, which should give you a text menu to start the root command prompt. From the terminal, try to fix the gdm3 by doing "apt-get install gdm3" If already installed, then try "dpkg-reconfigure gdm3"

Comment: @BernardWei Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the root command prompt by using Ubuntu advance boot option on booting up. Tap the down arrow key during booting if the boot menu doesn't stay up long enough. From the boot menu, select advance boot option, then select the recovery boot option, usually the second one from the top.

In recovery mode you are presented with a few menu choices, select the root shell prompt and from the console you could try to repair your setup by reinstalling gdm3.

```
apt-get install gdm3
```

And if it is already installed, try

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```